# Unix - how to merge two files using awk?

Tags: shell, awk

I have two unl files:

```
#a.unl
310123
23371043
23370043
300054
700988
#twenty records like these
```

and

```
#b.unl
310123|name1|
311123|name2|
#almost a hundred records like these
23371043|namex|
```

i want to use awk so that I could join a.unl records with names from b.unl like this:

```
#c.unl
310123|namea|
23371043|nameb|
23370043|namec|
300054|named|
700988|namee|
```

Is it possible using awk?
or do I have to use alternative like join?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}$1 in a' a.unl b.unl
```

Comment: btw, is there a way to print the result into, say, c.unl?

Comment: @junda Redirect the output: `awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}$1 in a' a.unl b.unl > c.unl`